# How to fix an overwritten repository?

Tags: git, github

Something's gone very wrong on a project I contribute to on GitHub.

There's a main repo, and my fork, which contains various improvements that are WIPs and not ready to merge back to the main repo yet.  I also have contributor access to the main repo.  But somehow Git seems to have screwed the whole thing up:

- Someone made a bug report, and I fixed the bug, with the code from the main repo checked out in my working copy.
- I committed the code locally
- I pushed the changes to the main repo

  - It gave me some nonsense error about some ridiculous Git thing called a "detached head", so I looked up instructions on how to fix that, and pushed the changes to the main repo.
- Suddenly the Master branch on the main repo is identical to my Master branch.  I was not working on my branch, and I did not tell it to merge my branch, but that appears to have happened, without even anything in the main repo's history that says I merged my Master branch.  It's as if it *overwrote* the branch instead of merging it!

Does anyone have any idea what happened, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the repo?

Comment: @PeeHaa If it helps: [Main repository](https://github.com/boo-lang/boo).  [My fork](https://github.com/masonwheeler/boo)

Comment: Can you show us the exact command lines you used for each of your bullet points?  You said "Git seems to have screwed the whole thing up", but it sounds like that means "I ran the wrong command".

Comment: @larsks Command lines are for scripts; they have never been a worthwhile user interface, so I did the whole thing on TortoiseGit.

Comment: It's easier to help you recover from a situation like this if you can tell us what you did to get there.  It doesn't matter if the steps were cli commands or a series of step in a GUI.  It looks like Isaac has tried really hard despite the lack of information, so kudos to him.

Comment: @larsks That's the entire problem, though.  If I knew what I had done to get there--or, more specifically, what I did differently this time--I wouldn't need to ask for help to fix it.  AFAIK I did the exact same workflow I've done any number of times in the past, and it's never screwed up like this before!

Comment: _"I did the whole thing on TortoiseGit"_ - that's your problem. TortoiseGit is a horrible tool, get rid of it as soon as possible.

Comment: @1615903 Can you recommend a better UI?

Comment: I used Git Extensions for a while when I started with git, but command line is really the best there is.

Comment: @1615903 Meh.  TortoiseGit may be "a horrible tool" but at least it has a proper UI.  *A command line is not a user interface.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to take a guess, when you were alerted that you needed to fix the bug, you did a `git checkout upstream/master`.

That put you in detached HEAD state.  There is nothing ridiculous about this--it just means that the commit you have checked out (HEAD) does not have any local branch pointed to it (hence the HEAD is detached).  You can continue to add new commits in that state, but before you push the new commits, you'll want to give them a branch so that you can refer to them later.

Next, you fixed the bug and wanted to push the changes, so you tried `git push upstream` and got an error message about how you have to be on a branch.  You may have believed that HEAD was already on master at that somehow git got confused, but that is incorrect.  HEAD was a commit you just created, whose ancestor is `upstream/master`, but your local master was something else entirely, most likely a descendant of `origin/master`.

At that point, a few things might have happened:

1) Maybe you thought, "I'm supposed to be on master, so let me `git checkout master` to straighten that out".  So you checked out master and pushed it upstream.

2) Maybe you thought "Git can't figure out what branch I want to push upstream, so let me add that as an optional argument: `git push upstream master`.  Depending on what version of git you are using, and the value of `git config push.default`, this may have pushed master, not HEAD, without it even being checked out.

#### HOW TO FIX IT

If you are still in detached HEAD state (on the commit you wanted to push upstream), then you need to take these steps:

(This example assumes the project's main repo is called `upstream`.  Typically, when using github, the project's main repo is `upstream` and your fork is `origin`.)

1) You'll need to rename your current master to something else temporarily, so that you can call this master:

```
git branch --force temp-branch master
```

2) call the current HEAD master:

```
git branch --force master HEAD
git checkout master
```

3) force-push the new master:

```
git push upstream master --force
```

4) Clean up and get back to your previous state:

```
git checkout temp-branch
git branch --force master temp-branch
git checkout master
git branch -d temp-branch
```

If you already checked out another branch, then before you can follow the above steps, you need to find that commit.

Look in `.git/logs/HEAD`--it's a record of every time HEAD changed.  grep the file for any part of the commit message you remember, and in that line, you'll see 2 commit SHA's.  The first is the one you were on before committing, and the second is the SHA of the new commit.  Checkout the second one to get back to where you were.  You'll be going back into detached HEAD state, but this time, you know what it means.  No matter how badly you mess things up, as long as you know this SHA, you can always come back to it and start over.

Comment: When you say "your main repo" do you mean *my* main repo, or the project's main repo?

Comment: Yes, that was a little ambiguous.  I clarified it.

Comment: How is it not ridiculous to be able to check out something with no associated branch?  Even Mercurial doesn't let you screw up that badly, and Mercurial is horrible and glitchy from beginning to end!  (Or at least, if it does, I've never ran across the right combination of HG screwups that causes it to happen...)  What is the use case for a detached head?

Comment: There are lots of use cases.  When you're doing a rebase, for instance, if there's a manual conflict to resolve, or you are doing an interactive rebase and stop somewhere to reword a commit message, or to edit the commit itself, it would be pointless for git to create a branch every time it pauses the rebase.  The same applies to `git bisect`: You checked out a commit temporarily, it's already an ancestor of the branch you're working on, and you won't need to come back to it later.  Imagine if git required you to assign a branch name to every single commit before you can bisect or rebase.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't assign a branch name to every single commit; you would simply *work on that same branch*.  I'm seriously not seeing what the point you're trying to make is supposed to be.  It almost sounds as if you're describing the way Mercurial handles local commits existing at the same time as remote commits (by making two sub-branches within the same branch, which you have to integrate before pushing to remote) and turning it into some sort of horror story.

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit, that automatically follows you if it's checked out.  If 2 branches point to the same commit, you don't want them both to re-point to a new commit when you add one, so git must be able to distinguish when a branch should follow and when it should not.  Checking out a branch is your way of telling git, "I want this branch to follow HEAD when I add a new commit".  If you want to add a commit without a new branch--for instance, if you're adding a new commit in middle of a rebase--then you don't want to have a branch checked out.

Comment: If you have any further questions about this, please ask a new question on SO about why someone would want to be in detached HEAD state, and hopefully someone else can explain this to you better than I can.